# Updating MYSQL PHP Form

Tags: php, mysql

I've searched all over the web but unable to find an awnser for my error, i'm doing a simple update form for php mysql and it's just not updating it.

See my code below

Form:

```
<form class="" action="edit_account.php" method="post">
              <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" value="<?php echo $r['username']; ?>">
              <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="username" value="<?php echo $r['name']; ?>">
              <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="username" value="<?php echo $r['email']; ?>">
              <input type="text" name="country" placeholder="username" value="<?php echo $r['country']; ?>">
              <input type="submit" value="Edit" name="submit">
            </form>
```

edit_account.php

```
session_start();
include("db_config.php");
include("../templates/sitehead.php");
$query = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '". $_SESSION['email'] ."'");
$r = $query->fetch_assoc();
$profile = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM `users.profiles` WHERE `user_id` = '". $r['id'] ."'");
$p = $profile->fetch_assoc();

if(isset($_GET['do']) == "submit") {    
    $username = clean($connect, $_POST['username']);    
    $connect->query("UPDATE `users.profiles` SET `username` = '". $username ."' WHERE `user_id` = '". $r['id'] ."'");
}

$query = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM `users.profiles` WHERE `id` = '". $r['id'] ."'");
$p = $query->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: You are checking `if(isset($_GET['do']) == "submit")` didn't you mean to check `if(isset($_POST['submit']) == "edit")`?

Comment: Your `UPDATE` code is inside `if(isset($_GET['do']) == "submit") {`, but you have `action="edit_account.php" method="post"`. So where do you get `$_GET` from?

Comment: @RST `Edit` instead of `edit`

Comment: Either way `if(isset($_XXX['do']) == "submit")` is a false positive. It needs to be split into 2 separate conditions. Edit: to @all of the above who made a mention of that non-working condition.

Comment: Plus, we also don't know where this is coming from `$_SESSION['email']` and whether or not it does have a value.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following statement:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) &&  $_POST['submit'] == "Edit") {
}
```